# Trying to read XML file variables in PHP

Tags: php, parsing, xml-parsing

I have an xml list of plans like this:

```
<plans>
  <plan>
        <name>LITE</name>
        <description>description</description>
        <rate>$9/Month</rate>
        <price>5</price>
        <period>1</period>
        <units>MONTH</units>
        <recurring>1</recurring>
        <acl>2</acl>
    </plan>
    <plan>
        <name>PRO</name>
        <description>description</description>
        <rate>$10/Year</rate>
        <price>5</price>
        <period>1</period>
        <units>YEAR</units>
        <recurring>0</recurring>
        <acl>3</acl>
    </plan>
</plans>
```

But I am not sure how to parse out the "period" and "units" params. I am trying like this but I think there is something wrong - like I'm not addressing the DOM properly.

```
    //$plan is already set above.   
    $plans_xml = simplexml_load_file( "../plans.xml" );
    foreach ($plans_xml->plan->name as $item){
        //if the plan in the xml matches the plan the user signed up for
        if ($item == $plan){
        //set interval by concatenating period and units
        $interval = ($plans_xml->plan->period . $plans_xml->plan->units);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($plans_xml->plan as $item){
    var_dump( $item->name );
}
```

Gives,
LITE
PRO

So then you can do your conditional check